# Foreign Key Syntax Error Table not being created

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

My table is not being created because of a FOREIGN KEY syntax error but I cant seem to figure it out. I made sure I created the int first before I called the FK. Here's teh code for my class with the FK

```
public class PlayerStatsDatabase  {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String PLAYER_ID = "PlayerId";
 public static final String KEY_SCORE = "Goals_Scored";
 public static final String KEY_MINUTES = "Minutes_Played";
 public static final String KEY_SUBIN = "Substitute_In";
 public static final String KEY_SUBOUT = "Substitute_Out";
 public static final String KEY_BOOKING = "Booked";

 private static final String TAG = "PlayersStatsDatabase";
 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Players";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "PlayerStats";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

 private final Context mCtx;

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
  KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
  PLAYER_ID + "integer"+" FOREIGN KEY ("+PLAYER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ROWID+"),"+
  KEY_SCORE + "," +
  KEY_MINUTES + "," +
  KEY_SUBIN + "," +
  KEY_SUBOUT + "," +
  KEY_BOOKING + ")" ;
```

The primary Key is in this class

```
public class PlayerDbAdapter {

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Players";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Player_Name text not null, Player_Position text not null, Player_Number text not null, Team text not null);";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
  public static final String KEY_BODY = "Player_Name";
  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_TITLE = "Player_Position";
  public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "Player_Number";
  public static final String KEY_TEAM = "Team";
private static final String TAG = "PlayerDbAdapter";
  private final Context mCtx;
  private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
  private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

  public PlayerDbAdapter(Context paramContext)
  {
    this.mCtx = paramContext;
  }

  public void close()
  {
    this.mDbHelper.close();
  }


  public long createPlayers(String playerName, String playerPosition, String playerNumber, String team)
  {
    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
    localContentValues.put(KEY_BODY, playerName);
    localContentValues.put(KEY_TITLE, playerPosition);
    localContentValues.put(KEY_NUMBER, playerNumber);
    localContentValues.put(KEY_TEAM, team);
    try{
        return this.mDb.insert("Players", null, localContentValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Juma", e.getMessage());
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

LogCat

`04-18 19:28:08.544: E/Database(352): Failure 1 (near "FOREIGN": syntax error) on 0x2b5840 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE if not exists PlayerStats (_id integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,PlayerIdinteger FOREIGN KEY (PlayerId) REFERENCES Players (_id),Goals_Scored,Minutes_Played,Substitute_In,Substitute_Out,Booked)'.`

Is it because i'm not inserting Player_id on the oNCreate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified  example I took from the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

```
CREATE TABLE track(
  KEY_ROWID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, 
  PLAYER_ID   INTEGER, 
  KEY_SCORE   TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY(PLAYER_ID) REFERENCES anotherTable(THE_KEY_ROWID_HERE),
  FOREIGN KEY(KEY_ROWID, PLAYER_ID) 
          REFERENCES yetAnotherTable(THE_KEY_ROWID_THERE, THE_PLAYER_ID_THERE)
);
```

As you can see, you have to add foreign key *after* all column definitions - don't try to put them *inside* the column definitions. You can have more than one, and also foreign keys with combined columns.

Finally be carefully when building the SQL String, your statement:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists PlayerStats (
 _id        integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
  PlayerId  integer,
  Goals_Scored,
  Minutes_Played,
  ...
```

... is missing the types for some columns.

**p.s.**: this one should work, for instance

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
    KEY_ROWID      + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
    ANOTHER_COLUMN + " text" +")";

 private static final String SQLITE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
    KEY_ROWID   + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
    PLAYER_ID   + " integer,"
    KEY_SCORE   + " text," +
    KEY_MINUTES + " text," +
    KEY_SUBIN   + " text," +
    KEY_SUBOUT  + " text," +
    KEY_BOOKING + " text,"
    +" FOREIGN KEY("+PLAYER_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ROWID+"))";
```

Hope I could help a bit.

Cheers!

Comment: If I type `DATABASE_TABLE` which is my table name that i'm referring to in my other class  I get an error, How would I initiate it?

Comment: Have a look at the small example; important: create the one above first, cause of the dependency.

Comment: This worked. However am I recreating the same table from the other class but only if it doesn't exists correct? This wouldn't create duplicate tables and give me errors later on? Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what `if not exists` is for. Only the order of table creation is important.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the name of the primary key as _id in android sqlite.

Comment: I did this in both classes did I not? `KEY_ROWID` is my Primary Key. I've realised they're both the same so i've renamed the second one `KEY_ROWID2` but now how do I link `PLAYER_UD` to `KEY_ROWID` which is in a different class?

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, you have a syntax error near "FOREIGN", its clear that there is not space between "PlayerId" and "integer", in addition of the comma after integer. moreover, you didnt submit types for [Goals_Scored,Minutes_Played,Substitute_In,Substitute_Out,Booked].

I suggest to learn more about SQL queries, you can start with using sqlite on desktop.

Comment: I didn't submit types intentionally just wanted to see if the table was being created.